# How to get correct time using momentJs

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to get the correct time using `momentJS`. Below is my code

```js
let time = moment("1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z", [ "h:mm A", ]).format("HH:mm");
console.log(time)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.28.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

when I use the above, it returns me time as "19:00"

Can someone please suggest how do I get the correct time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to pass any formatting like  `[ "h:mm A", ]` when formatting a date or time from an `ISO` Date. You just need to use like this:

```
moment("1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z").utc().format("HH:mm");
```

Also, we need to use [.utc()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) function to make sure we are getting the **correct** UTC and not local time.

**Live Demo:**

```js
let getTime = moment("1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z").utc().format("HH:mm");
console.log(getTime) //17:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.28.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-Q1f3TS3vSt1jQ8AwP2OuenztnLU6LwxgyyYOG1jgMW/cbEMHps/3wjvnl1P3WTrF3chJUWEoxDUEjMxDV8pujg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```